# Error updating XML file on Android

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, document

I'm trying to edit an XML file on Android and when I do the update, if the String that I'm adding to a node is greater than the one by default, my XML becomes corrupted.

If I have:

```
<Configuracion>
  <CamposEditables>Empresa</CamposEditables>
</Configuracion>
```

and I add ", Web" to the node I get:

```
<Configuracion>
  <CamposEditables>Empresa, Web</CamposEditables>
</Configura
```

I've added 5 chars to a node but my file keeps having the same name of chars so it takes 5 chars from the end of the file.

Here is my code:

```
File filexml = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString() + "/configuracion.xml");

DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filexml);

Node nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Configuracion").item(0);
NodeList list = nodes.getChildNodes();

for (int i = 0; i<list.getLength();i++)
{
    Node node = list.item(i);

    if("CamposEditables".equals(node.getNodeName()))
    {
        String camposeditables = "Empresa, Web";
        node.setTextContent(camposeditables);
    }
}

TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();

DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(filexml);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Thanks in advance for the help you can give me.